# How do I determine the "size" of my diamond pattern?

Tags: php

I want to change the size of my diamonds however I want using form inputs. For example, I want my diamond to have a size of 15, then the "stars" in the middle should have 15, and the rest follows.

This is my current code, in this case it has size "9", because the stars in the middle of the diamond has 9 counts.

```
echo "<table border = 1 align = center>";

// loop for the pyramid
  echo "<tr>";
    $max = $initAmount = 10; // 10
    for($i = 1; $i <= $initAmount; $i += 2) {
        $max = $max - 2; // 8
        $halfTD = (int) ($max / 2);

        echo "<tr>";
        for($b = 1; $b <= $halfTD; $b++){
            echo "<td></td>";
            }
                for($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++) {
                    echo "<td bgcolor = $color>&nbsp;$char&nbsp;</td>";
                }
                    for($b = 1; $b <= $halfTD; $b++){
                        echo "<td></td>";
                    }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";

// loop for the inverted pyramid, so it looks like a diamond

    $max = $initAmount = 10;

    for($i = 7; $i >= 1; $i -= 2) {     
        $max = $max - 2;
        $diff = $initAmount - $max;
        $blankTd = $diff / 2;

        echo "<tr>";    
            for($b = 1 ; $b <= $blankTd; $b++){
                echo "<td></td>";
            }
            for($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++) {
                echo "<td bgcolor = $color>&nbsp;$char&nbsp;</td>";
            }   
            for($b = 1 ; $b <= $blankTd; $b++){
                echo "<td></td>";
            }

        echo "</tr>";
    }

echo "</table>";
```

Output:

[image]

In what part of my code should I fiddle with to get a custom size?

Comment: Fiddle with `$max` `$initAmount` and any other variable containing a number.

Comment: It works! Thank you. But it appears it just works when working with even numbers. When I enter an odd number, the "white spaces" is incomplete. Maybe it's because of the `$max = $max - 2;` and  `$halfTD = (int) ($max / 2);` calculation. How do I make odd numbers work? For example 11.

Comment: Try fiddling with those too. Honestly there are probably much more efficient ways to write this.

Comment: Sounds like you need to refactor your code to make it more efficient. Since you you have an odd number of squares when using numbers which can be divided evenly your diamond will always have 2 squares on each tip when specifying odd numbers as your base.